# Create a file structure / dictionary tree in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, file, dictionary, structure

I wrote a vba function that fetches a file structure (paths of folders and their subfolders) from a database and saves it in a dictionary, similar to a hash.

Now, i want to either create a worksheet **or** a userform, that creates a file structure from the dictionary similar to this:

[image]

Basically a file structure where the user can browse folders and subfolders, and has the option (for example with a checkbox) to select and deselect the innermost folder (which contains scripts, and all selected scripts will be executed..).

Is there any structure like this or anything else similar that does the job in either an excel worksheet or a VBA userform?

Comment: https://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/treeview00.asp

Comment: thanks, this might be exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of something that might be what you're looking for:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim vStartFolder As Variant
    Dim sFolderPath As String

    'If blank, the browse window will start at computer root
    'If populated, the browse window will start at the specified folder location
    vStartFolder = ""

    'Show a Folder Browser that will let the user select a folder
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder", 0, vStartFolder)
    If oFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel
    sFolderPath = oFolder.Self.Path & Application.PathSeparator

    'Folder selected, do what you need with the selected folder
    MsgBox sFolderPath

End Sub
```

Running that will open a Folder Browser that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Cool.  And if one wants to early bind to the type library you're using then they can tick Tools->References->Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, i dont know why somebody downvoted this, this is a solid answer. Sadly i fetch the file structure from a perl-maven webframe running on a linux server, so i can't just open it like this. The idea is to get the file structure from the webframe, let the user browse the folders and select some scripts he wants to start, then send the information back to the webframe. Maybe its wrong to use Excel VBA here at all, i just already programmed some VBA classes to access the webframe for a different project, so i hoped i could just use those functions here too.